# Basic Expression Expansion

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I expand  this expression $(1-x^2)^{-5/2}$  as a series in x?

I'm looking eventually for a series in $x_1$ and $x_2$ where $x$, $x_1$, and $x_2$ are magnitudes of $\vec{x}$,$\vec{x_1}$, and $\vec{x_2}$  and $\vec{x}$ = $\vec{x_1}$ + $\vec{x_2}$

Comment: Do you know how to expand $(1-y)^{-5/2}?$.  You can do that with the binomial theorem.  Now set $y=x^2$

Comment: Please correct me:
$(1-x^2)^{-5/2} = 1 +\frac{5}{2}x^2 + \frac{35}{8}x^4+\frac{105}{16}x^6$

Comment: [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Expand+(1-x%5E2)%5E(-5%2F2)) agrees with you.  You can click more terms to get as many as you want.

Comment: thank you for ur help